# Flutter Web - How do I retain an absolute value when iterating a list of objects?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a list of dictionaries within which I have an id.
I iterate over the list and create a raised button.
The raise button 'onPressed' is intended to send the 'id' that was in the 'product' at the time it was created, however it always sends the 'id' from the last 'product' object in the list. It seems that it retains a relative link to the product object rather than the absolute value of 'id'. (the ** are just for highlighting the object and are not in the code).

```
if(productList!=null)
  for(product in productList)
     TableRow(
       children: <Widget>[
         Container(
           decoration: new BoxDecoration(
             color: Colors.white,
           ),
           child: Center(
             child: Row(
               children: <Widget>[
                 SizedBox(
                   width: 50,
                   height: 20,
                   child:RaisedButton(
                     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                       borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                     ),
                     onPressed: () => editProduct('**${product['id']}**'),
                     color: Colors.blue,
                     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(1, 1, 1, 1),
                     child: Text('Edit',
                       style: TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         fontSize: 10,
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I have tried every combination of conversion to string I can think of. toString(), wrapping in single quotes, double quotes. Any suggestions?

Comment: could you show where that item is being used? If is on a ListView or similar, you can compare index value with the length of the list and then get the value from that list. Please, provide that extra info and I'll create an example for you.

Comment: As can be seen in the code, I am using a Table and the object in question (highlighted with the ** ** as indicated) is the "onPressed" action of a RaisedButton within a SizedBox within a Row within a Center within a Container within a TableRow.
When used within a ListView, the system retains the index that it finishes with so that all onPressed objects index value is the number of objects in the list and you get an 'out of bounds' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `for(final product in productList){...}`

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for why this solution works? It would make it easier for people to find this solution in the future

Comment: I got around that particular problem by not using tables, however when I eventually tried it again for a different test, this worked. There may have been a modification in one of the updates to dart as well as .toString() also worked this time.